# What does `String longest = ""` mean and do?

Tags: java, string

This is the bottom portion of the of my program. My friend helped me out; however he didn't explain the `String longest = "";` part.

```
public static void longestName (Scanner z, int x){
    String longest = "";
    for(int i= 1;i<=x;i++){
        System.out.println("Insert Name "+i+":");
        String name=z.next();
        if(name.length()>longest.length()){
            longest=name;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(longest+"'s name is the longest");
}
```

Comment: Well, it's just an initialization with a string of length 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `String longest=""` and getting input `name`. Then if the length of the input name is longer than the `String longest` then the new name is set as `longest`.

Answer (score 0):

Its saying Naim's name is the longest.

"'s is needed to add 's to persons name